# How to skip a python list field

Tags: python, json

im using a print function to retrieve some fields from a json list:

```
def printws():
    while True:
        message = pyjq.all((ws.recv()))
        print("Event:", message[0]['imdata'][0][%]['attributes']['dn'] + ' ' + "was" + ' '+ message[0]['imdata'][0]['attributes']['status'])
```

the "%" values changes depending on the received payload, i want to retrieve 'atributes' and 'dn' no matter the field (as a side note it always start with fv), how can i achieve this?
sorry for the rookie question :)
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you try something like

```
def printws():
    while True:
        message = pyjq.all((ws.recv()))
        for i in message[0]['imdata'][0]:
            if 'fv' in i:
                key = i
        m1 = message[0]['imdata'][0][key]['attributes']['dn']   
        m2 = message[0]['imdata'][0]['attributes']['status']
        print(f"Event: {m1} was {m2}")
```

Comment: If multiple fields have ‘fv’ in them, try incorporating regular expressions; or if the ‘fv’ key is always the same length, try adding a condition that accounts for length.

Comment: it returns NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: if i replace i for dic it returns TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: That “i” shoulda been dic. I was trying to clear up my answer. What does a sample of the data you get look like, if it isn’t a dictionary, but starts with ‘fv’?

Comment: Regardless of what your data looks like, the point of my proposed solution is: your data has multiple layers. Go down a number of levels you know don’t change, then use some kind of loop to get the unknowns.

Comment: "imdata": [
        {
            "fvTenant": {
                "attributes": {
                    "annotation": "tag_tenant",
                    "childAction": "",
                    "descr": "%s",
                    "dn": "uni/tn-demo_tenant",
                    "extMngdBy": "",
                    "lcOwn": "local",
                    "modTs": "2020-04-23T23:38:05.451+01:00",
                }

Comment: in this case we have fvTenant

Comment: Edited it. Try that. Get to the unknown layer and do some kind of check to find what you seek.

Comment: Yep going down to levels that don’t change should work, but I’m not able to pass that fv field..how can I put a regular expression so that anything should match for instance...

Comment: (Also, sorry if I sounded pretentious or sumthin anywhere in my comments; my intent was to be helpful and encourage, rather than issuing lectures or sound high n mighty)